# SSAS 2008 Account provision

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, ssas

During SSAS 2008 installation the Account provisioning tool comes up and you can select the current Windows user (or other windows user).  However that account was deleted prior to adding another user as the administrator.  In 2005 the tool existed on the server and could be run manually, however I’m not seeing it in 2008.

I assume I can uninstall and reinstall to do this, however is there another way how I can add an admin account?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default accounts that have local administrator rights on the server will also be SSAS admins, so such an account should be able to access the server in Management Studio and add other users as SSAS administrators.

If this option is turned off a server admin can always navigate to ..\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\OLAP\Config\ and change the BuiltinAdminsAreServerAdmins setting from 0 to 1 in the msmdsrv.ini file and restart the SSAS service and then add other admins in Management Studio.